# How to deploy a winforms application into Azure DevOps

Tags: winforms, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am looking for a step by step guidance to deploy a c++ winforms application into Azure DevOps.

I have a legacy application and its already into TFS server but now the team has planned to put it into Azure DevOps and automate the builds and release process.

I did some researches and tried something and it partly worked out. But, I cannot understand whether to go by GIT or TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control)?

As, the application is already into TFS, I believe it will be easier to create the repository and pipeline using TFVC. But, what if I want to do using GIT? What are the factors I should consider when using GIT?

**NOTE: I do not have TFS server access but I do have Azure DevOps access.**

**What I have tried:**

Created a demo project. Below are the details about the demo project:

```
<code>Project and Solution Name -> SampleApp
Solution file location -> "C:\SampleProj\SampleApp\SampleApp.sln"
Other project files location -> "C:\SampleProj\SampleApp\SampleApp"</code>
```

Tried to deploy the above sample project into Azure, using GIT. The steps I followed are given below:

```
<code>
1. Installed GIT.
2. Logged into dev.azure.com with my credentials.
3. Created a new project and copied the 1st link as provided in "Repos" section.
4. Created a ".gitignore" file from Visual Studio Team Explorer -> Settings -> Repository Settings.
5. Went to the project folder (C:\SampleProj\SampleApp\SampleApp\) and right-clicked and selected "GIT Bash Here". The GIT command prompt opened up and typed the following commands:

a. git init
b. git remote add origin [URL copied at step 3]
c. git add .
d. git commit
e. git push -u origin master
</code>
```

After these steps, the repos in Azure were holding all the files except the solution file (.sln) and when I created pipeline for builds, the builds started to failed as it was not getting the .sln file.

I cannot understand the below mentioned points:

```
<code>
1. For all projects, I cannot find Repository Settings in Team Explorer. Why so?
2. If I have a legacy application already in TFS, can't I make it done using TFVC instead of using GIT?
3. What are the correct steps being followed in the industry?
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I did some researches and tried something and it partly worked out.
>   But, I cannot understand whether to go by GIT or TFVC (Team Foundation
>   Version Control)?

Git is distributed system while TFVC is centralized system. More into about their difference you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=azure-devops).

> But, what if I want to do using GIT?

About moving from TFVC to Git you can consider using [git-tfs tool](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs). More details check [this guide](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/usecases/migrate_tfs_to_git.md).

> Tried to deploy the above sample project into Azure, using GIT. The
>   steps I followed are given below:

If you have a newly created project, you can easily add it into git source control in Visual Studio and then push it to Azure Devops Service project. Please check [Share your code with Visual Studio 2017 and Azure Repos Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-vs-2017?view=azure-devops-2019#create-a-local-git-repo-for-your-project).

> For all projects, I cannot find Repository Settings in Team Explorer.
>   Why so?

You need to add the solution into source control in VS first, then you can find repository Settings in `Team Explorer=>Settings=>Repository Settings`.

[image]

Hope all above helps and it could be better to separate the different questions in your post into different threads.